# Conditional formatting on dates in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to use conditional formatting on dates. I want the formula to underline only Saturdays and Sundays, and to make Monday number 0 in days of a week (Ex. Monday=0, Tuesday=1, Wednesday=2, etc).

I have no idea how to do this, so I'd like some help.
Thank you.

Comment: `WEEKDAY([yourdate])` will return a number for each day of the week

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, Super User is not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 2):

Would be great if you showed some format, data, formula etc. of the sheet you're working with. That makes it easier to help you.

You might want to try:

1. **Add a column** with the formula **=WEEKDAY([date],3)** - "3" is the type you're looking for with Monday as number 0.
2. **Mark** the whole table.
3. Add new **conditional formatting rule** with "Use formulas to determine..." (I assume you know how to, otherwise [check the Microsoft support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) or watch some Youtube videos).
4. Type in the formula **=$B2=5** (for Saturdays), **=$B2=6** (for Sundays), or **=$B2>4** * to cover both - where B is your weekday column, and 2 the first row of values. Make sure the $-sign is exactly like that.
5. Go to "**Format**" and choose the styling, e.g. underlining.
6. Press OK for the formatting and OK for the rule.

   [image]

(*) thanks for the hint, @fixer1234